# Mysql Truncate Table, Auto Increment not working

Tags: php, mysql

So i just truncated my table but now my primary key will not auto increment.  Every time I add a 2nd item to the table, it comes back with 1062: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

I thought when you truncate a table it will just resets the auto increment back to 1.

I search around on what I could do but I have come across many people saying just truncate.

What I did

```
"TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;"
```

I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `DESCRIBE mytable`.

Comment: Ensure that your primary key column is still defined as auto_increment.

Comment: refer http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-o-1844.html

Comment: try with dropping and creating the table again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bug not affects Mysql 5.0 and it is repeatable on 6.0  and 5.1.23 and 5.1BK.

[Refer this link for proof](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37531)

Following is readily available and effective workaround is to ALTER the autoinc value after the table is truncated.

Re-initialize the autoinc value right after truncation

`alter table tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = n;` /* set n as desired */

Comment: thanks, I had a feeling about it being a bug but I wasn't sure

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL 5.0.13 , the AUTO_INCREMENT counter is reset to zero by TRUNCATE TABLE, regardless of whether there is a foreign key constraint.

All you need to do is:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

truncate your tables and change it  back to

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Once TRUNCATE is fired, the table handler does not remember the last used AUTO_INCREMENT value, but starts counting from the beginning. 
This is true even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence values.

Answer (score 0):

User this Query it will work.

ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `table_id` `table_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT