# MySQL master master replication error - Duplicate key in Magento on insert into

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We are trying to do master master replication for DataBases and Magento's DB is giving us issues:

Error 'Duplicate entry 'hle9agote6b43tvnrl3c3n9g76' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'magento_d'. Query: 'INSERT INTO `core_session` (`session_expires`, `session_data`, `session_id`) VALUES ('1352860963', 'K6uI7suW8PVkzYh6wxLoKjy_gyxavZpSUfNN2QwDkjw85sRHcGN1EjDFHhOH22uof3qvTOwDUHJISln-f8jYENR6SDGZgSxYtzw_cqZZP0yVB1rY6WwMH-AEEHvJAhGeZWCv6-QEbQR1iA83KE0-nxgqcUR0KGpyFBt5LvWcX9osNXMFcrN5aPII3JXJQw4F2bprP_HiF2qNh3NqWsU4LBq3mLN9GYTaHBprLkeQ4LyOkpI0IL67jWuBnvc8wzg3eHWbbesETSXSgjv59mKJOmN2vqpabhBaqLgyItLDNLo4v8jotbf1evrKvpYTbfpht1bDe89HMgJT-5fRenOkyddTwlHzoKK7uKaDpUN7kdkzcDUOFZNDTlBRKo447R_zTP4jk_6UQlDcAO10QKiW8L9PQkF5qB-GB_7xsJyEoH5e7Ysef27BGtztpjdO-PCLwgUQ4GJ4oftOv4RYj-EtKD5WL6TKDcvxxJzCnE2aSAINVW92bu0oYwhJQn3-cy4JhxQsh48PAJq1xcG9gVpsuzaJ4rbDrQZ45_yN41-MVpHaiM73M24tFsZdGe5LLVnb7zRxMfdTF1ZfTuuaK-8TB4mPsFIVDRuJEGBjHlsx2BXDHFucaLxnfR5ibGjgiGZaDKUS2CmLyAAsHV7rSKGOy0ArSIS4PJrnh4vQbylodN4JK4z19nPRDt1yxbsn8uf0zSYa11G2SLZsPFz0vk7AUVWlCtKsmKdCBtR6F3lNg_9M88JMtVirbpwhNQbCDIQZ-4nm793wrQmfuuT1bloA0ZpMfQi1ouEZEjL

From what I can tell I think the auto_inc needs to be different for magento_d on one of the masters (shop2).

[Mysql Truncate Table, Auto Increment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744547/mysql-truncate-table-auto-increment-not-working/10744675#10744675)

**Check page 38, 39:**
http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/PLMCE2012/PLMCE2012-Diagnosing_Failures_in_MySQL_Replication.pdf

So, all I need to do is on one of the master's make magento_d's core_session table auto increment differently? How would you guys approach this issue. I just don't want to corrupt anything and cause myself more work/headache.

Best Regards,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

What we did is:

1. Login as root user to MySQL
2. switched to the DB with table core_session...--> use magento_d
3. deleted the contents from core_session...--> delete from core_session;
4. changed the auto increment value for core_session to avoid conflict in future...--> alter table core_session AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;
5. master master replication works now and no conflict

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that by adding appropriate indexes to the core_resource table, or saving sessions into Redis or Memcache, or Truncating the whole table, that would solve the problem TEMPORARILY, but not definitely...other problems (duplicates, foreign keys) will come up in other tables and stop replication.

In order to fix this, you should use MySql row-based replication and  binary logs in row format, otherwise those errors will keep on stopping replication.

Give it a try and let us know your result if you're still experiencing this issue.

Cheers.